# SliverAppBar() not collapsing with ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to display tabs for each main tab (Nested Tab Bar) in `SliverAppBar()`. It's look like this:

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llrPe.jpg)

[See the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqifD.gif)

The content of the exam tab it's in `Container()` widget (That the error in the image came from).
Now, with the `Container()` widget the `SliverAppBar()` will collapse when the user scroll the exam tab content (white screen in the image), everything is fine for now.

So, After I replaced the `Container()` with `ListView.builder()` to make the tab content scrollable, now I can't collapse `SliverAppBar()` from the tab content (white screen in the image). but I can from the `SliverAppBar()`.

[See this GIF after I added ListView.builder()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mygq.gif)

So, How I can make the SliverAppBar scrollable (collapsing ) with Listview?
**Can** anyone **help** me? please :(

This example (demo):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'SliverAppBar App Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return [
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                  handle:
                      NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                  child: SliverSafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    sliver: SliverAppBar(
                      pinned: true,
                      title: Text(widget.title),
                      expandedHeight: 500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                    TabBar(tabs: [Tab(text: 'Tab A'), Tab(text: 'Tab B')]),
                    Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  pinned: false,
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                NestedTabs('A'),
                NestedTabs('B'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This class is to handle the main tabs (Tab A & Tab B)
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar, this._color);

  TabBar _tabBar;
  final Color _color;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      color: _color,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class NestedTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  final String mainTabName;
  NestedTabs(this.mainTabName);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(20),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab $mainTabName-1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab $mainTabName-2')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: 500,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.black45,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Index ${index}')));
            },
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: 500,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.black45,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Index ${index}')));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You have an overwhelming amount of information and no specific question. Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but I was thinking it was clear :(. My question is how I can make the SliverAppBar scrollable (collapsing ) with Listview

Comment: I would advise you to remove all the code and descriptions that aren't specific to your problem and leave only the essential.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code and wrote full example

Comment: I have faced the same issue, and the question is clear to @JoãoSoares, why are you saying it's not clear. The GIF says it all.

Comment: @IdrisStack If you understand and have faced the same issue. Please provide an answer.

Comment: I haven't got an answer

Comment: Facing same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Use SliverList() instead of SliverFillRemaining for ListView